# How do i understand firebase query in android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have list of posts in firebase realtime databse.
And each item has unique id.
Example is shown in below image.

[image: expanded]

For retrieving data from firebase i used this query.

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts").limitToLast(4)
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) 
                             {
            Post post= snapshot.getValue(Post.class);
PostList.add(post);
                                     }
                                }
                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                }
                            });
```

I used `limitToLast(4)`.
Means i will get the last 4 item and `PostList` fill like.

```
First Element(last fourth node value)
second Element(last third node value)
third Element (last second node value)
fourth Element (last node value)
```

So, Now the problem is that i want reorder in `PostList`.

```
First Element(last node value)
second Element(last second node value)
third Element (last third node value)
fourth Element (last fourth node value).
```

Comment: Please expand one of those childs and add it to y our question.

Comment: i changed image the expanded node

Comment: To solve your problem, just change the type of your date to by of type `timestamp` and not `String`. Check the duplicate to see how you can achieve this.

Comment: you mean i have to set orderbychild(timestamp(long)) value

Comment: That's right ;)

Comment: Before calling limitToLast you always need to call orderByChild(key).

Comment: @ Alex Mamo: how can i set this question is solved